# How get all style of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have style like this :

```
.filter {
      background-image: url("../images/index.png"); !important;
      background-blend-mode: difference !important;
      filter: invert(1);
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px black;
      **other style**
    }
```

and I wanna get all the style it is possible ?

if I want get with property-name like

```
$(selector).css(property-name:property-value);
```

I should write many line code for it because the style is many.

- I can not use inline style and get it with attr

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the properties of a single CSS class, but you can get all the computed style of an element:

```
var e = getElementById('myElement');
console.log( getComputedStyle(e) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getComputerStyle`

```js
const h3 = document.querySelector("h3");
const result = document.getComputedStyle(h3).content();
```

[GetComputedStyle Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Also you can use `getAttribute` method with `style`

```js
conat h3 = document.querySelector("h3");

let styles = h3.getAttribute("style");
styles.replace(" ", "")
    .split(";")
    .map(s => s.split(":"));
```